# How setcolor in tabSpec text?

Tags: android

this my code adds TabHost:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

                tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
                tabSpec.setIndicator("My text");
                tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, listlayout.class));

                tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

How setcolor in tabSpec text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
    TabHost tabhost = getTabHost();
    TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#492353"));
```